# "You had to come in now?" One word for describing a negative reaction

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

X is annoyed, but not angry. I'm thinking of a couple of possible options:

- Protests
- Groans
- replies

One person opens the door, and X (a kid) is in the middle of something. What word best describes how X is feeling? It doesn't have to be any of the above.

> "You had to come in now?" _________ X.

where ______ is the qualified response. Is there a good word for this kind of reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest  [complain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complain): (from M-W)

> - to say (something that expresses annoyance or unhappiness)

- .. 'Complained X'

Answer (score 0):

[*Irritated*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irritate) captures the meaning well: to cause (someone) to feel impatient or angry; annoy. -AHDEL

Annoyed, but in a non-intense, fleeting way i.e. it will soon pass.

> "...replied X, (clearly/slightly) irritated."